# Stuck with a java Math

Tags: java

I am stuck with some java math question. I've been trying and trying but can't find a solution.

Can anybody post the result with sample java code please?

The question is:

**given a list of number from 1-100, any number is divisible by 3 is replaced by X, and any number is divisible by 5 is replaced by Y, if  a  number divisible by both become 'XY'.**

Comment: You basicly have the code and the logic behind it written in the task, what do you think would be the first step that needs to be done, given that you are about to check the numbers from 1-100?

Comment: I sniff student homework..

Comment: This assignment is called the [Fizz Buzz Test](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest).

Answer (score 0):

```
String repNum;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    if(i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0){
        if(i%3 == 0){
            repNum = "X";
        }
        if(i%5 == 0){
            repNum = "Y";
        }
        if(i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0){
            repNum = "XY";
        }
    }
    else{
        repnum = String.valueOf(i);
    }
    System.out.println(repNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your numbers into an arraylist or array.
2. Check array value one by one using loop.Then use if else clauses to make the logic.

   `for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {`

   `if(array[i]%3 ==0)`

   ```
    `array[i]="X";`
   ```

Above is an example . So hope you can understand , how to implement rest of it.
Try it . if you wan more help inform me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
String replaceNum;
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
    if(i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0){
        replaceNum = "";
        if(i%3 == 0){
            replaceNum = "X";
        }

        if(i%5 == 0){
            replaceNum += "Y";
        }

        list.add(replaceNum);
    }else{
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```